# Rundeck - Run Steps dynamically based on input Options

Tags: rundeck

I'd like to run number of *steps* based on different input *Options*.

For example, I've a *Job* that runs a `./script.sh` with *year* as input param:

```
./script.sh <year>
```

the idea is to set a list of "years" as *Options* params (something like `2018, 2019, 2020`) and run a `script.sh` for each year and each `script.sh <year>` should be run as a single *Step*.

- step_1: `./script.sh 2018`
- step_2: `./script.sh 2019`
- step_3: `./script.sh 2020`
- step_n: `./script.sh n`

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 2020-04-22**

Expected on Rundeck where each *Command* has one year:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this example, using an option that passes it to an inline script that iterates using `@option.myoption@` (and referencing the "external" script step as argument).

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='theyear' value='2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>a72d4d32-d4fe-4774-b18c-723d18842c5e</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>WhatYearIs</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/bash
DataList=" @option.theyear@ "
Field_Separator=$IFS

# set comma as internal field separator for the string list
IFS=,
for val in $DataList;
    do
        # echo $val
        bash /path/to/your/script/year.sh $val
    done

IFS=$Field_Separator]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a72d4d32-d4fe-4774-b18c-723d18842c5e</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

The bash script to test:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# print_args.sh
echo "Current year is:" "$@"

# You could pass all arguments to another program like this
# myProgram "$@"
```

**UPDATE:** You cannot add steps dynamically on a job meanwhile runs, but, another way to do that is basically a modification of the first suggestion, the difference is that we call another job through [rd-cli](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) tool on inline-script that calls (and pass the year as an option) to execute as an individual step.

**WhatYearIs Job (As parent job).**

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='theyear' value='2018,2019,2020' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>SO</group>
    <id>a72d4d32-d4fe-4774-b18c-723d18842c5e</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>WhatYearIs</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/bash
DataList=" @option.theyear@ "
Field_Separator=$IFS

# set comma as internal field separator for the string list
IFS=,
for val in $DataList;
    do
        # echo $val
        sleep 3
        rd run -p ProjectEXAMPLE -j WhatYearChild -- -childyear $val
    done

IFS=$Field_Separator]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a72d4d32-d4fe-4774-b18c-723d18842c5e</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

**WhatYearChild (As child job that executes the script).**

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='childyear' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>SO</group>
    <id>76c15c6d-be45-4540-8f44-8823ed2d2483</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>WhatYearChild</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "Current year is: @option.childyear@"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>76c15c6d-be45-4540-8f44-8823ed2d2483</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

With [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDL3o.jpg) result (technically is an individual step of each iteration).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this code doesn't generate dynamically Steps; I'll heave always the output (Command/Script) on a single Step. 
Please view my UPDATE on top.

Comment: Hi! You cannot add steps dynamically on a job meanwhile runs, but, I added another way: basically is call another job (through rd cli tool) from the inline script passing the year on each iteration. Check the update.